# SQL Case statement Syntax

Tags: sql-server, case

I am trying to write a select statement that will select a number of fields including an email field.  There are 3 email fields available in this table which can sometimes contains null values.  I wan to look at 3 fields; [email address1], [email address2], [email address3] and basically what I want to do is if [email address3] is null then I want the value in [email address2],  If email address2 is null than I want the value in [email address1]

I can't seem to get the Syntax right and am not too sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Consider rewording the question title to better match the answers

Answer (score 11):

What you need is [COALESCE(...) function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258244.aspx):

```
SELECT COALESCE(t.Email3, t.Email2, t.Email1) FROM MyTable t
```

Comment: Good call, although I think the questioner would need the arguments reversed.

Comment: I think the order is correct, the question is worded in an strange way though.

Comment: if both Email1 and Email2 are not null, your result will be Email1, whereas OP asks for Email2.

Answer (score 5):

No need for CASE, you can also use [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) ("Returns the first nonnull expression among its arguments"):

```
SELECT COALESCE(Email3, Email2, Email1) ...
```

Answer (score 2):

See other answers about COALESCE, but if you really *want* a CASE structure, this should do it:

```
CASE
  WHEN email3 IS NOT NULL THEN email3
  WHEN email2 IS NOT NULL THEN email2
  WHEN email1 IS NOT NULL THEN email1
  ELSE ''
END
```

I added the else clause to prevent returning a Null from the whole thing, but if that's what you want to happen when all three are Null you can use:

```
CASE
  WHEN email3 IS NOT NULL THEN email3
  WHEN email2 IS NOT NULL THEN email2
  ELSE email1
END
```

Note that the SQL Server CASE function does not drop through cases--once it matches one, that's it. No need for a "break".